# Can't read xml when running from executable .jar

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I'm saving some settings in an xml insinde of my resources folder. This all works fine until i try to run my software in my executable .jar file where it can't fild it.

I added the resource in my pom.xml and if i check my .jar file i can see the .xml in the classes folder.
When i debug my .jar file get an exeption on the Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xml) that it could not find the file:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\dante\IdeaProjects\BACbrowser\file:\C:\Users\dante\IdeaProjects\BACbrowser\backend\target\backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes!\defaultSettings (Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch)

```
public void readXMLSettings() {
    try {

        File xml = getXmlSettingsFile();
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xml);

        setPort((doc.getElementsByTagName("port").item(0).getTextContent()));
        setSiteName(doc.getElementsByTagName("siteName").item(0).getTextContent());
        setSiteDescription(doc.getElementsByTagName("siteDescription").item(0).getTextContent());
        setBacnetSeparator(doc.getElementsByTagName("bacnetSeparator").item(0).getTextContent());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Can't read XML settings");
        ;
    }
}

private File getXmlSettingsFile() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    URL resource = classLoader.getResource("defaultSettings");
    if (resource == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("file is not found!");
    } else {
        return new File(resource.getFile());
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the Name of the file and where is ist located?

Comment: In spring boot you don't need to create xml files to make configurations within your application. There is support for many flexible way to make configuration possible. Can you explain why are you trying to do that by hand (not using Spring Boots options)..?

Comment: The name of the file is defaultSettings and its in the src/java/resources folder. 
I do this by hand because i'm not familiar with spring boot and the way of creating configurations in it. But thanks for the info, cheking it out right now.

Comment: try `Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("defaultSettings.xml");
File file = resource.getFile();`

Answer (score 0):

Using the application.properties from Spring Boot and directly saving the settings there worked just fine!

```
spring.boot.config.settings.port = BAC0
spring.boot.config.settings.siteName = Anlage
spring.boot.config.settings.siteDescription = Site
spring.boot.config.settings.bacnetSeparator = '
```

By adding a `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.boot.config.settings")` prefix on my class i was able to access them without problems.

```
private String port;
private String siteName;
private String siteDescription;
private String bacnetSeparator;

public String getPort() {
    return port;
}

public void setPort(String port) {
    this.port = port;
}

public String getSiteName() {
    return siteName;
}

public void setSiteName(String siteName) {
    this.siteName = siteName;
}

public String getSiteDescription() {
    return siteDescription;
}

public void setSiteDescription(String siteDescription) {
    this.siteDescription = siteDescription;
}

public String getBacnetSeparator() {
    return bacnetSeparator;
}

public void setBacnetSeparator(String bacnetSeparator) {
    this.bacnetSeparator = bacnetSeparator;
}
```